# How to rotate Android touch-screen via hid-usb driver

Tags: android, hid, touchscreen

I'm building Android 5.1 with kernel version 3.10.52. Everything goes fine before I attached a hdmi touch screen (http://www.waveshare.net/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(B)). HDMI output was fine and it's landscape, and touch function was working. But the direction of touch function is different from HDMI output. Touch screen is functioned via USB port by hid-usb driver.
In Linux dist, we usually use Xorg and the libinput config to calibrate. But now it's on Android, and I really don't know how to rotate touch screen. 
Could anyone help?